# A SQL statement with boolean with sort

Tags: sql

Okay so like occasionally, our caller's and the helpdesk operator's who takes the call have the same first name. And what I want to do is list the names that have the same first name and then sort into alphabetical order. So far with our database I've tried to form the statement but I don't typically do SQL.

```
SELECT First_name, Last_name, Assigned_to, Taken_by
FROM Staff, Issue
```

and now its like I want to use boolean to list the first names where this is true, once each in alphabetical order.

Comment: `where First_name = Assigned_to order by First_name `

Comment: it's not using boolean though so output is null

Comment: Please improve your grammar / formalism.  Also, can you clarify what it is you are hoping to get as output?  And what have you tried so far?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

If I understodd correctly, you want to `GROUP BY` the first name and filter the first names occurring more than once in the `HAVING` clause. `INNER JOIN` that result with the table and `ORDER BY` the names.

```
SELECT t1.first_name,
       t1.last_name,
       t1.assigned_to,
       t1.taken_by
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t2.first_name
                               FROM elbat t2
                               GROUP BY t2.first_name
                               HAVING count(t2.first_name) > 1) t3
                       ON t3.first_name = t1.first_name
       ORDER BY t1.first_name,
                t1.last_name;
```